# Is being simply connected very rare?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, computational-topology

Essentially, my question is how strong a restriction it is to be simply connected.

Here is a way of making this precise: Let's say we want to count simplicial complexes (of dimension 2, though that does not matter much, any fixed dimension is fine) on N simplices that are subject to the following restrictions:

A: every vertex is contained only in a bounded number of simplices (say, 10000).

B: the complex is simply connected.

So properly: How many distinct complexes like this are there? In fact, I only want a rough answer: is it exponential in N, or is it superexponential. Note that if I remove either restriction, the answer is superexponential.

Comment: When asking [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327909/are-most-spaces-aspherical) (which is sort of a stronger version of your question), I learned that there are many models of what a "generic" or "random" simplicial complex should be, and moreover that the answers to questions like this are sensitive to the choice of model. Do you have strong reasons for preferring a model where the "valency" is bounded over, say, a model where there is a constant probability that a given subset is a simplex?

Comment: There are also things to say about the general question "is simply-connectedness restrictive?" which are "orthogonal" to the business of trying to pin down a model like this. For instance, even if $X$ is not simply-connected, it has a universal cover $\tilde X$ which is simply-connected, and the relationship between the two spaces is close enough that if you understand $\tilde X$ well, then you understand a great deal about $X$ too. So even if simple connectivity _is_ restrictive in some context, it's often still quite useful to have a good understanding of simply-connected spaces.

Comment: You might find some relevant information in the paper of Babson, Hoffman and Kahle: The fundamental group of random 2-complexes. J. Amer. Math. Soc. 24 (2011), no. 1, 1–28.

Comment: @tim the valency is bounded because it seems to make the problem interesting. Suddenly, there seems to be an order of magnitude less of simply connected than all other topologies

Comment: Are you counting up to isomorphism? (I expect so, just to be sure)

Comment: @SamHopkins but counting multiplies by $n!$, which affects the growth rate.

Comment: Note that it is open whether the number of (simply-connected) complexes with the topology of the $d$-sphere is exponential or superexponential in $N$ for $d \geq 3$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, but one possible approach is to count triangulations of simply-connected 4-manifolds with integral homology sphere boundary. The 2nd homology has intersection form given by an integral unimodular lattice. The number of integral unimodular lattices grows super-exponentially in the dimension. If one could construct bounded valence triangulations of 4-manifolds realizing these intersection forms, which has linear growth in terms of the 2nd betti number, then this might show superexponential growth of such triangulations.

Comment: @YCor Indeed, I count up to isomorphism

Comment: @IanAgol I tried something similar, but wasn't able to keep the valence and number of simplices down at the same time. That of course does not mean it cannot be done.

Comment: It seems to be that this is an open problem even if you count simplicial complexes with fixed bounded first Betti number. If I am wrong I would be very interested to know.

Comment: @Bruno right. I am unsure whether this is a homology phenomenon or a homotopy issue

Comment: Gromov says in a talk that this is connected with a question about graphs. How many graphs are there with bounded valence whose first Betti number is generated by cycles of simplicial length at most N (that is, made of at most N edges)? We know that trees are exponential and graphs are super-exponential. If you fix N you are somehow in the middle, and it seems that the answer is unknown. I don't remember precisely the problem, so I might have forgotten something.

Comment: @BrunoMartelli what talk? Do you have a reference?

Comment: https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SpacesandQuestions.pdf
page 33

Answer (score 10):

Here's a rough estimate indicating that indeed, in this "bounded-valency" model, a simplicial complex has nonvanishing fundamental group with high probability. We'll actually conclude something stronger: the number of 2-simplices is *bounded* with high probability. I think this points to a deficiency of the "bounded valency" model -- intuitively I would expect a "good" measure on simplicial complexes with $N$ vertices to tell me that the expected number of 2-simplices grows with $N$.

Let $N$ be the number of vertices, and let $d$ be the bound on the number of simplices containing a given vertex. Let's think about a 2-complex $X$ in this model as follows:

- The 1-skeleton $X_1$ of $X$ is a graph with valency bounded by $d$, and so has $\leq Nd/2$ edges. Its fundamental group is a free group on $\leq N(d/2-1)-1$ generators. Let's assume that $X_1$ is connected or at least is dominated by a giant component, and that we're interested in the fundamental group of the giant component.
- Now each 2-simplex we add can only shrink the fundamental group, so we might as well add in all possible 2-simplices and see that the result is still not simply-connected. The probability that a given pair of vertices is connected by an edge is $\sim (Nd/2) / {N \choose 2} \sim d/N$. So given a vertex and two edges connected to it, the probability that these fit into a triangle is $\sim d/N$. So each vertex is contained in $\sim {d \choose 2}(d/N) \sim d^3/(2N)$ triangles, and so there are a total of $\sim \frac 1 3 N(d^3/(2N)) = d^3/6$ triangles.

That is, the fundamental group of $X_1$, which is free on a number of generators $\sim N(d/2-1)$ growing with $N$, is quotiented by a *bounded* number of relations $\sim d^3/6$ with high probability. By looking at abelianizations, we can see this implies that $H_1(X) \neq 0$ and in particular that $\pi_1(X) \neq 0$.

---

Of course, if you take $d \sim 10000$, then the bound on the number of relations is about a trillion, so you need to look at pretty big complexes before you see this behavior emerge :).

---

I think the main "non-rigorous step" of this argument lies in assuming that the probability for two vertices $v,w$ to be connected by an edge *does not go up* when we condition on the event that $v,w$ are each connected to a third vertex $u$. This seems very plausible to me (if anything the probability should go down a bit because one of the possible $d$-many vertices for $v$ to be connected to is taken up by $u$ and similarly for $w$), but I'm not sure how to actually justify it.

Comment: This seems like it's answering a different question than whether the number of simply connected complexes with bounded valence grows exponentially or super-exponentially in $N$.

Comment: @SamHopkins I'm (sketchily) answering the weaker question of whether the number of simply connected complexes with bounded valence grows _more slowly_ than the total number of complexes with bounded valence, i.e. whether "most" complexes of bounded valence are non-simply-connected. My understanding was that the idea of asking about exponential growth was primarily motivated as a strengthening of the question I've attempted to answer.

Answer (score 6):

The following does not answer your question, but adding just in case it is helpful.

If you weaken "simply connected" to $H_1(\Delta, \mathbb{Q}) = 0$, and weaken "every vertex is in a bounded number of edges" to "the average number of triangles containing an edge is bounded", then there are super-exponentially many such complexes. This is an old result of Kalai, on enumerating $\mathbb{Q}$-acyclic complexes. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02804017
There are $\exp( cn^2)$ such complexes, where $c>0$ is some constant not depending on $n$.
For the latest on enumerating $\mathbb{Q}$-complexes, see Linial and Peled:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rsa.20841

Andrew Newman and I recently showed that a typical $\mathbb{Q}$-acyclic complex (according to a natural `determinantal measure') is not simply connected. With high probability, the fundamental group is a hyperbolic group of cohomological dimension 2.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.13572

Comment: Hi Matt, if you weaken to average degree being small, then getting superexponentially many is very easy; you can just take cones over graphs. It seems the question is only really interesting if you bound the degree uniformly.